# Button text don't wrap when used with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have 2 buttons next to each other (chained), and there are 2 states possible in the app, either only the left button is visible in which case it should be centered horizontally, or both are visible in which case they both should be horizontally centered. This all works, however there are multiple words in the buttons, and on small screens the buttons both get clipped instead of wrapping.   To fix this setting the width to 0dp on both buttons work, however in this case the buttons become as wide as they possibly can, so it does not look right on larger screens or when only one button is visible. My question is how do I wrap the words in the buttons when using ConstraintLayout? How do I constrain the buttons so they wrap properly and don't become wider than they need to be? With LinearLayout this all works out of the box, but I want to use ConstraintLayout. I tried setting app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" on both buttons but this does not work, what it will do is wrap only the first button and it will wrap it out of existence if the second button has a long enough text.

**Update:** I updated the button text to be longer in the example.

XML:

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Long text for first button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/objectAboveButtons"
                app:layout_goneMarginEnd="0dp"
                app:layout_goneMarginRight="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Long text for second button"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/objectAboveButtons" />
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong, cause I tried to copy this code and it works just like you need to, just with little change in constrains.

Comment: I anonymized the text and maybe "Text for button1" is a bit short, if you make it bit longer it will clip left and right, at least it does on my samsung galaxy s4.

Comment: So there is a need to make text going the second line and so on?
I checked some answers. You could set the text programmatically including `\n` to make the width correct.

Comment: Yes, for example if layout_width is 0dp, then the words will wrap automatically when needed, and it will do it equally for both buttons so they have the same width, but the problem with this approach is that the buttons will take up all available space instead of being only as wide as they need to. I want the buttons to expand as much as they need to but not more than they need to. I'm not sure about setting `\n` programmatically since it shouldn't wrap if it doesn't need to.

Comment: If you specify could the width that you need and then apply it to the button text it will work. Because the only thing that is changed is text and only if `getWidth()` is bigger that it could fit. It is not an elegant solution, I know. But if you give it a try :)

Comment: @axlrtr didn't my answer work or help you to achieve what I wanted? If it did, could you please accept my answer? I' would appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` in the buttons and set the width to `0dp` instead of `wrap_content` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Long text for first button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Long text for second button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_50_pc"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline_50_pc"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've used `Guideline` to distribute the width evenly between buttons when it contains larger texts like the ones provided in the problem. Change the `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf` of `Button2` programmatically from `Guideline` to `Button1` when its visibility is in `GONE` state:

```
if (button2.visibility == View.GONE) {
    ...
     constraintSet.connect(R.id.button2, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.button1, ConstraintSet.END, 0);
}
```

Screenshot with the longer texts provided in the question, with both buttons wrapped around them:
[image]

Screenshot with the button 2 gone:

[image]

Comment: This worked almost so I will approve it. I also had to add a horizontal bias constraint and move the buttons towards the center when both are showing by having bias to 1.0 for button1 and 0.0 for button2, so that they get centered on larger screens or in landscape, however when only the first button is showing the bias has to be 0.5 otherwise it would fill the whole width. I also don't think the weight is needed for the buttons. Thanks.

Comment: Adding app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" was what I needed. Why this isn't automatically taken care of by the framework I can't imagine. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Although SaadAAkash answer is correct, at least in androidx constraint layout 1.1.3, `layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` is deprecated and the correct way is the following:

1. Replace `layout_width="0dp"` with `layout_width="wrap_content"`
2. Replace `layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` with `layout_constrainedWidth="true"`

It should yield the same results.